# App Engine Django-Nonrel ReferenceProperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am in the process of upgrading an App Engine Python/Django application from the (old style) App Engine Helper to the (new style) Django-Nonrel. Each model now inherits from `django.db.models.Model` instead of (old style) `appengine_django.models.BaseModel`.

My database models are declared as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class UserModelBackupTracker(models.Model):
...

class UserModel(models.Model):
    # The following line generates the error
    backup_tracker = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=UserModelBackupTracker)
```

Which triggers the error:

```
"reference_class must be Model or _SELF_REFERENCE" (in appengine.ext.db.\__init__.py -> ReferenceProperty.\__init__ ).
```

This error is triggered by a check to see that the reference_class "issubclass" of `google.appengine.ext.db.Model`, however the declaration of that class is of type `django.db.models.Model`, which is *not* a subclass of `ext.db.Model`.

So, the question I have is: What am I doing wrong with respect to declaring the ReferenceProperty when using Django-Nonrel, and how should I fix it.

Kind Regards
Alexander

Comment: Using the class db.Model (instead of the django.db models) as the parent of the classes seems to fix this problem.